# Select2 list of elements moves outside datatable when using a cellphone

Tags: javascript, datatables, jquery-select2

I have a responsive datatable that renders a Select element with Select2 on each row. Everything works as expected on a PC. But when using a cellphone, whenever a select is opened, the list of elements moves to the top of the page (outside the datatable).

this is the code I tried:

```js
    $(input).select2({
       dropdownParent: $("#tblTratamiento"),//tblTratamiento is the datatable
    });
```

I'm not sure what the problem is: If I am not specifying the `dropdownParent` correctly or the fact that the datatable is responsive.

**This is how the the list of elements looks on cellphone**

[image]

Comment: Does replacing `$("#tblTratamiento")` with `$(input).parent()` help you?